# Is there a way to safely delete QList of non-unique pointers to MyObject?

Tags: c++, qt, list, shared-ptr

I know this kind of question has been asked to death but I would like to know if there is anyway to do what I stated in the question **without** using Boost library pointers etc. Basically I have the following piece of cleanup code that deletes objects pointed to by the pointers in the double-dimension QList ( QList< QList > )

```
#include <QList>
QList< QList<MyObject*> > m_Data;
...
void CleanupMyObjectList
{
int numFrames = m_Data.size();
for(int i=0; i < numFrames; i++)
{
    int numObjects = m_Data.at(i).size();

    for(int j=0; j < numObjects; j++)
    {
        MyObject* removedObject = m_Data[i].at(j);
        if(removedObject != NULL)
        {
            delete removedObject;//This assumes that the pointers are UNIQUE in this list!!! If not it will crash!!!
            removedObject = NULL;
        }
    }
    m_Data[i].clear();

}

m_Data.clear();
}
```

and it indeed crashes when I try to clean up the list populated by non-unique or shared (is this the correct term?) pointers, for example when m_Data[0][1] is equal to m_Data[1][1].

I know why it crashes so please save the explanation for that but rather I want to know if there is anyway to safely delete these objects with as little modification of the code as possible.

Comment: Is myObject perhaps derived from QObject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a temporary `std::set<MyObject*>`. Iterate over m_Data, and instead of deleting the pointers straight away, add them to the set. Next, delete all pointers in the set. There are no duplicates in a `std::set`.

<sub>You can safely delete a `NULL` pointer. No need to check that</sub>

Comment: Nice! I never thought of using a temporary container to do the job. I supposed I can also use QSet from Qt library to do the same thing right?

Comment: Just tried out the suggested solution and it worked perfectly! Thank you all for the quick replies

Answer (score 1):

Because u don't want to use boost shared pointers ,
you can use `QList< QList<QSharedPointer<MyObject>> > m_Data;` instead of `QList< QList<MyObject*> > m_Data;`